# How to connect to AWS VPN from a country that blocks most VPNs

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services

For work, I must connect to AWS cloud services via the AWS VPN app that my company setup on the company laptop that I use. The AWS VPN only provides access to my company's space in AWS (EC2, S3, console, etc.). All of my work involves connecting to an EC2 instance. The company and I are based in the US.

Sometimes I travel to Egypt. Egypt blocks most VPNs. In particular, the AWS VPN fails to connect from Egypt, and so I cannot access the cloud to do work from Egypt.

I imagined that one workaround could be that I run some other VPN from Egypt, and then run the special VPN "inside" of it. This does not work. In particular, I successfully ran NordVPN from within Egypt, but I could not connect with the AWS VPN app while the NordVPN was running.

I called many popular VPN providers that claim to support multi-hop/double hop/cascading VPNs, but they all told me that it was not possible to run the AWS VPN while their VPN was running.

How can I run the AWS VPN from within Egypt so that I can access my company's space on the cloud?